# I should be able to undo a vote on an answer I once upvoted without editing if I put a bounty on the question

Tags: discussion, edits, bounty, voting

Assume I have received an answer once which I upvoted and marked solved because it contained a helpful workaround and no other answer has been received for weeks. Now, working intensively with it I realize that the workaround is much more limited than I thought and decide to put a bounty on the question to get a better answer than a workaround. I can undo the "solved" mark, but I cannot undo the upvote without the answer being edited. That's good behaviour if there's no bounty, but against my interests and the best outcome of the bounty and the question if there's a bounty set.

Example: [How to avoid log being displayed after travis_wait?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46636196/how-to-avoid-log-being-displayed-after-travis-wait)

Comment: Why did you upvote it before you fully tested it?

Comment: @Davy actually, since we all know there is such a thing as pity upvotes.... I'd be worried of giving that power to users. They'll downvote themselves to get some pity rep and come out ahead -_-

Comment: It's partially your fault when you upvoted it without testing. What you can do is to leave a comment under it explain which parts are wrong, hoping others whould not use that answer.

Comment: @user202729 Please not that I'm not questioning that in general, but only in case I set a bounty on it.

Comment: That doesn't make my statement wrong.

Comment: The easy answer is that you have enough rep to do a very minor edit on the answer that goes through without review, then you can un-upvote. It's a bit of a clunky workaround sure

Comment: @Patrice I thought about it, but it feels like cheating/hacking SO.

Comment: Oh I get that feeling of course. Just saying it is a possibility

Comment: Make a minuscule edit such as code formatting or put two spaces somewhere, remove your upvote, and then roll back your edit. Additionally, based on your description the answer sounds like it was at least correct for some time so why do you wish to downvote it?

Comment: @KarlRichter Patrice did not specify the edit rollback. It's allowed, legal, and publicly logged so if you feel like you're "cheating/hacking" SO then add a comment when editing such as "minuscule edit so I can remove upvote."

Comment: @MonkeyZeus Right, I just want to undo an upvote.

Comment: Once you've edited their answer then just click the upvote arrow to remove the upvote, no need to downvote.

Comment: Honestly, your edit comment further confuses me with what your goals are. If you are going to re-upvote after the bounty has been awarded then why remove the upvote at this point? Is this some ploy to encourage other people to answer? If someone else has an answer then they will answer regardless of the scores of existing answers. I would have personally just unchecked the "Accepted" checkmark and added a comment as to why their ultimately failed for you.

Comment: This person will not be explicitly notified of your edit nor your vote removals and by the looks of things there is a chance that this person could update their answer with a desired solution based on their expertise if they were made aware of their answer's shortcomings.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus If I leave the upvote the system will reward him the the bounty. Giving him an upvote is fine, but not the bounty, therefore I'll temporarily remove the upvote until the bounty is expired and give it back after. That represents my feeling how much this answer deserves. I didn't know about the notifications because I always seem to get one for edits and votes.

Comment: Minor edits do not automatically notify the user nor do downvotes/score-loss. As for awarding the bounty, read the [How is a bounty awarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty) section.

Comment: @Karl But... a bounty us auto awarded only if the answer is posted during the bounty period and have score >1.

Comment: @
MonkeyZeus
 please don't give people suggestions on ways to abuse the edit system to reverse votes

Comment: @YvetteColomb You're suggesting it youself in your answer.

Comment: @KarlRichter I am making no such suggestion. Making a trivial edit like this is an abuse of the edit privilege.

Comment: @KarlRichter I do not intend to be rude at all, I can edit that out. But I do want to make this clear. It is not what the edit system was intended. It's supposed to be a substantial edit, that changes the content of the post, which may then cause a voted to want to reverse a vote. I would not recommend making a habit of this or for anyone else to do this either. Yes the bounty system can be confusing.

Answer (score -2):

Frankly this type of editing to reverse a vote is really bad form and not necessary. The bounty will not be automatically awarded to an answer that was posted before the bounty  was placed.

"... the highest voted answer created ***after*** the bounty started ..."

A trivial edit so you can reverse your upvote to help ensure the question will not get a bounty, then after the bounty is awarded you'll put the upvote back is an abuse of the edit system. If a post deserves an upvote it deserves an upvote period.

> ### [How is a bounty awarded?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/bounty)
>
> If you do not award your bounty within 7 days (plus the grace period), the highest voted answer created after the bounty started with a minimum score of 2 will be awarded half the bounty amount (or the full amount, if the answer is also accepted). If two or more eligible answers have the same score (their scores are tied), the oldest answer is chosen. If there's no answer meeting those criteria, no bounty is awarded to anyone.
>
> If the bounty was started by the question owner, and the question owner accepts an answer posted during the bounty period, and the bounty expires without an explicit award then we assume the bounty owner liked the answer they accepted and award it the full bounty amount at the time of bounty expiration.